# ER_BAD_DB_ERROR on connecting to database using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, sequelize.js

I have a project that utilizes the npm packages mysql, Sequelize and redis.

The following goes well:

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db:   2,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'
  }),
  secret: 'secret' // changed this value of course
}));
```

And then:

```
Sequelize.connection = new Sequelize('test_ddb',
  'root', 'root', { logging: false });
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'test_ddb'
```

I tried a couple of things, first I thought Sequelize is not connecting to MAMP's mysql but the my system's mysql, but I had all the symlinks already setup. Like so:

```
/var/mysql/mysql.sock -> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I even changed it here:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
```

The mysql command in the terminal also utilizes the MAMP database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure MySQL is running? Can you connect to it with the MySQL command line client?

Comment: Yes command-line client works and I can connect to the database with mysql -u root -p test_ddb

Comment: @Pepijn it might be that Sequelize (or rather, the underlying MySQL driver) needs to use TCP to connect to MySQL, instead of using a Unix domain socket. Check to see if the MySQL server is configured to accept TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the idiomatic way of initializing Sequelize:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('test_ddb', 'root', 'root')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused usually if there is no database in the first place.

`CREATE DATABASE` in mysql before you run Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from Node.js with mysql integration and indicates that there is no database with the entered name:

```
[code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR', errno: 1049, sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'database_name']
```

Firstly, you can edit your code a bit to see what databases you have:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'YourPass',
// Note that we are intentionally not passing any database name (And yes it still works :))
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database');

  // Execute the SHOW DATABASES query
  connection.query('SHOW DATABASES', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error retrieving databases:', err);
      return;
    }

    // Extract the database names from the query results
    const databases = results.map((result) => result.Database);

    console.log('Available databases:', databases);
  });

  // Close the database connection when done
  connection.end((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error closing the database connection:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Database connection closed');
  });
});
```

Now you already know from the print statement if the database in fact does exist or no. If not, just create new database with that name like following:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'YourPass',
    // Note that we are intentionally not passing any database name (And yes it still works :))
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database');

  createDatabase('test_db'); // Avoid using hyphen in db names or you will need to change to underscore after facing error message when trying to run it
});

function createDatabase(databaseName) {
  // Execute the CREATE DATABASE query
  connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${databaseName}`, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error creating database:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Database ${databaseName} created successfully`);
  });
}

// Close the database connection when done
connection.end((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error closing the database connection:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Database connection closed');
});
```